# ICANN Name collision for react-native android

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, react-native, rack-pow

I have a react-native app with ios and android versions.  Both versions use a webview to access a web site.  The ios version works when pointed to either the production web site or local development version.  The web site  uses `ruby on rails` and the development server is `pow`.

When I run the android app, it loads but when it tries to access a local version of the web site, it returns the following error:

```
console.error: "Encountered an error loading page", {"canGoForward":false,"code":-2,"canGoBack":false,"description":"net::ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION","loading":false,"title":"","url":"http://my_app.dev/,"target":69}
```

The same happens if I use localhost rather than the `my_app.dev`. It does however work when pointed to the external production url i.e `my_app.com`.

I have tried using a different android device, and the error changes to ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. The first device used the android browser whereas the second looks like it uses chrome. So it does appear to be a browser specific problem. Reading this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/919278/err-icann-name-collision-when-trying-to-use-localhost-dev-in-chrome), I used `nslookup my_app.dev` to work out the ip address as `127.0.53.53` and entered

```
127.0.53.53  my_app.dev
```

into the /private/etc/hosts file.  However this still gives same error.  How do I fix this?

Comment: This may help you: http://superuser.com/questions/919278/err-icann-name-collision-when-trying-to-use-localhost-dev-in-chrome

Comment: I have tried using a different android device, and the error changes to ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.  The first device used the android browser whereas looks like  it uses chrome. So it does appear to be a browser specific problem.  Reading the superuser answer, it is not clear what I should do. Should I add the my_app.dev to the hosts file, and if so,what IP address should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work around for this problem is to  find out the ip address of the development machine, say `192.168.0.33`, configure the server to allow external access at `my_app.192.168.0.33.xip.io`, and then in the react app, configure the host url as `http://my_app.192.168.0.33.xip.io`.  However this means running the server in special mode, so it would be better to find a direct answer to this question.